# Switch application in c# like task manager

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to write c# application which will switch between some running applications. It should do the exact functionality like Alt+Tab in windows. I use `SetForegroundWindow()` function from Windows API, but it does not work well if the application is minimized on the windows task bar. So I added `ShowWindow()` function, but there is one problem that I am not possible to show the window in the original size which user set.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
```

Example: I maximize window, then I minimize it into the task bar. When I call:

```
ShowWindow(processWindowHandle, ShowWindowCmd.SW_NORMAL);
WindowsApi.SetForegroundWindow(processWindowHandle);
```

The window is not maximized. I tried to play with the `ShowWindowCmd.SW_NORMAL` parameter but with the same result.

Comment: have you tried SW_RESTORE?

Comment: Yes I tried SW_RESTORE. The application which was maximalized and then minimalized is then displayed NOT maximalized (as expected). It is shown as window which size is lower then max size of the screen.

Comment: I don't want to maximalize the window every time. I want to show the window in the same state which was befor I hide the window with another one or befor I minimalized it into the task bar...

Comment: I have updated my answer, you need to supply the value 9 to the ShowWindow method to restore original state.

Comment: @JMK: 9 is equal to `SW_RESTORE`, so it is not the solution... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this before, you want to get a list of everything open, minimize everything, and then iterate through that again comparing each program with the one you want restores, and then restore that one. You need a way to identify that one window you want restored, I used to use the MainWindowTitle as I had control over the environment, and could therefore guarantee that each MainWindowTitle would be unique, you may not have that luxury.

The code I used in the past for this is below, it worked well:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

void SwitchDatabase(string mainWindowTitle)
{
        try
        {
            bool launched = false;

            Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process theProcess in processList)
            {
                ShowWindow(theProcess.MainWindowHandle, 2);
            }

            foreach (Process theProcess in processList)
            {
                if (theProcess.MainWindowTitle.ToUpper().Contains(mainWindowTitle.ToUpper()))
                {
                    ShowWindow(theProcess.MainWindowHandle, 9);
                    launched = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ThrowStandardException(ex);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. You are right, I think. There is only one small disadvantage. If I don't minimalize my window and call this code the maximalized window is restored into the NOT minimalizes and NOT maximalized size. Maybe there should be code something like this:
`if (minimalized)
 {
    ShowWindow(theProcess.MainWindowHandle, 9);
 }
 else
 {
    SetForegroundWindow(processWindowHandle);
 }`